# Why isn't the entry content displaying in my label?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I'm new to python and I'm having this trouble that I don't know how to get the content of an Entry widget and display it as the text of a Label widget.

I've tried with this code to make the text variable of the Label (t) have the value of the Entry when the button is clicked, but when I do so it just generates a blank space under the button. Here's the code:

```
import tkinter

main = tkinter.Tk()
main.resizable(0,0)

frame = tkinter.Frame(main)
frame.pack()

entry1 = tkinter.Entry(frame)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=0)

t = str

texto = tkinter.Label(main, textvariable=t)

def comando1():
    t = entry1.get()
    texto.pack()

boton = tkinter.Button(main, text="Presiona", command=comando1).pack()



main.mainloop()
```

I don't know practically anything about python so I accept any kind of help for me to learn. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `t` isn't a proper value for `textvariable`. It needs to be an instance of one of the tkinter objects `StringVar`, `IntVar`, `DoubleVar` or `BooleanVar`.

If `t` is defined an an instance of one of those variables, you need to set its value with the `set` method.

```
t = tkinter.StringVar()
...
def comando1():
    t.set(entry1.get())
    ...
```

On a final note, if you want the label to have exactly what's in the entry widget, then it will happen automatically if both the label and the entry widget use the same `textvariable`. The two widgets will always be in sync.